# Отключить подсвечивание красным у поля с type="email" в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

```
<input type="email" />
```

Если вводить всё, кроме e-mail, в Mozilla Firefox поле подсвечивается красным.

[image]

Каким образом это можно убрать? В поисковиках подобных вопросов не нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить в стили `box-shadow: none`.

**UPD**

```css
input[type="email"] {
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
```

```html
<input type="email">
```

Comment: спасибо! Получилось. Через 10 минут приму ответ.